# ¿En mongodb cual es la diferencia entre el error code 11000 y el error code 11001?

Tags: mongodb

dificilmente entiendo que el error 11000 trata sobre conflicto que hay.

el error 11001 no lo logro entender tengo este codigo

```
if(error.code === 11000 || error.code === 11001){
      var apiError = new ApiErrors.ValidationError(error.errmsg || 'There was 
      a duplicate key error', 409);
        next(apiError);
}
```

cual seria su diferencia?

Answer (score 0):

Según la respuesta de referencia levanta **11000** si se hace un `insert` para una clave existente, y **11001** si en lugar del `insert` se hace un `update` por mas que el texto del error, para este último caso,  diga **11000**.

Ref: [MongoDB difference between error code 11000 and 11001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032879/mongodb-difference-between-error-code-11000-and-11001)